# Partially sorting an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of arrays alphabetically at the exclusion of the word "Other", which is a member that I want at the end of the array. Let's say that the array looks like the following:

```
cities = [["Sidney"], ["Other"], ["Melbourne"]]
```

Simply saying, `cities.sort` just do the following:

```
[["Melbourne"], ["Other"], ["Sidney"]]
```

I would like the members to be alphabetically ordered with `["Other"]` at the end, like so:

```
[["Melbourne"], ["Sidney"], ["Other"]]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: There is code smell in what you are trying to do. If you want to do that, then you should exclude `["Other"]` from `cities`, and whenever you want the sorted list, you should do `cities.sort + [["Other"]]`.

Comment: @sawa: I agree, but I think you could have expressed it better. Perhaps I should say you had author smell? But that wouldn't be polite.

Comment: Is there only ever one `other`? If so then you have your answer: treat it separately from the sort. But if there are `other`, `other2`, `other3` etc. that must be sorted independently after everything else, then that is a different problem that you need to explain

Answer (score 1):

```
cities = [["Sidney"], ["Other"], ["Melbourne"]]
cities.delete_if { |x| x.first == ("Other") } #remove other from the Array and then sort by the city
cities.sort_by { |x| x.first }.push(["Other"])
#=> [["Melbourne"], ["Sidney"], ["Other"]]
```

Comment: your solution helped me solve my problem but in order to do so, I had to implement a solution differently, seeing as that the problem was more complex than I had originally represented it. I will create another question on SO and answer it. I'll also give you credit. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the link to the SO post that reflects the answer to my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043703/sorting-a-partially-sorted-list-in-rails/23043727#23043727

Answer (score 1):

```
cities.sort_by do |(city)|
  [city == 'Other' ? 1 : 0,  city]
end
# => [["Melbourne"], ["Sidney"], ["Other"]]
```

There are a few things going on here.  First is what's called a [*destructuring bind*](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html): `|(city)|`.  Each element of the `cities` array is itself an array, and we're interested in the first element of that array.  That's what the parentheses around `(city)` get us.

Next is that sort_by returns an array.  When two arrays are compared, the first elements of the two arrays are compared.  If they are equal, then the second elements are compared, and so on.  Because of this, we can use the first element of the array as the primary sort order:

```
city == 'Other' ? 1 : 0
```

and the second element of the array as the secondary sort order:

```
city
```

The primary sort order causes 'Other' to be put at the end of the sort.  Otherwise, the elements are sorted by city.

Comment: The downvote seems to indicate that this answer can be improved.  What can be done to make it better?

Comment: I withdraw my downvote. My problem with your answer was that you don't yet know the full requirement, and you have solved an imaginary question. But I have a habit that I want to correct of downvoting anything less than perfect. Your solution is fine

Comment: @Borodin Thank you, sir.  I do not see the ambiguity that you and sawa see, but I agree that the OP's question would be improved, and alternate solutions might well be suggested, if we knew the reason the OP wants to sort this way.

Comment: @WayneConrad your solution helped me solve my problem but in order to do so, I had to implement a solution differently, seeing as that the problem was more complex than I had originally represented it. I will create another question on SO and answer it. I'll also give you credit. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the link to the solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043703/sorting-a-partially-sorted-list-in-rails/23043727#23043727) that answered my problem. @WayneConrad Thank you so much for your contribution