# Sorting a Partially sorted list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

This question originally stems from another SO post I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037953/partially-sorting-an-array-in-ruby). However, the problem was in fact a Rails problem, and I tried to strip down the problem to make it more simple, which would give me answers more manageable and not frustrate individuals interested in helping. Here's the original problem:

In my initializers folder, I had a really complex collection, a hash of hashes with arrays. The collection looks like the following:

```
Locations = { :Australia => { :cities => %w(Sidney Melbourne Other),
                              :currency => 'AUD'},
              :Canada =>  { :cities => %w(Montreal Toronto Other),
                           :currency => 'CAD'},
              :England =>  { :cities => %w(London Other),
                           :currency => 'GBP'},
              :Israel =>  { :cities => ['Jerusalem', 'Tel Aviv', "Modi'in", 'Netanya', 'Haifa', 'Other'],
                            :currency => 'ILS'},
              :USA =>     { :cities => ['Chicago', 'Los Angeles', 'Miami', 'Teaneck', 'New York', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens', 'Bronx',
                                     'Washington', 'Other'],
                            :currency => 'USD'},
              :France =>  { :cities => %w(Paris Other),
                            :currency => 'EUR'},
              :Switzerland =>  { :cities => %w(Zurich Antwerp Other),
                            :currency => 'CHF'},
              :South_Africa => { :cities => ['Johannesburg', 'Cape Town', 'Other'],
                                  :currency => 'ZAR'},
              :Argentina => { :cities => ['Buenos Aires', 'Other'],
                   :currency => 'ARS'}
            }
```

In my views, I used the initializer to the sort the cities of the selected country with the following:

```
             tr
                -city_select = Locations.collect { |country_name, country_info | country_info[:cities].collect {|city| [city, city, class: country_name] } }.flatten(1)
                th
                  = f.label :city, '*City'
                td
                  = f.select :city, city_select, {}, id: 'property_city'
```

The problem was that when I selected the drop down, city, after selecting the country, the list would be unsorted. If I just added, `.sort`, on the block {|city| [city, city, class: country_name]}.sort, the group of cities would be sorted alphabetically, including the word "Other". I did not know how to partially sort the list of cities and append the member, Other, at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wayneThis answer my question:

```
          tr
            -city_select = Locations.collect { |country_name, country_info | country_info[:cities].collect {|city|    [city, city, class: country_name] }.sort_by { |(city)| [city == "Other" ? 1 : 0, city]}.push(["Other"]) }.flatten(1)
            th
              = f.label :city, '*City'
            td
              = f.select :city, city_select, {}, id: 'property_city'
```

Thanks to @WayneConrad and @bjhaid, I was able to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.  Do consider putting `city_select` into a helper.  Views are easiest to read and work with when they don't have much code in them.